# join expression to linq query

Tags: c#, linq, expression

first of all, sorry for my stupid question.
i have a class

```
person{

public string name, addr;
}
```

i also got a datacontext which return a person entity when i call this

```
 myDbcontext dbContext = new myDbcontext();
    var _query = from pson in dbContext.GetTable<person>() where pson.name = "somename" select pson ;
    return _query.First<person>();
```

'cause i'm quite new to C#. I dont know is there a way to write a general function like this

```
getPerson(person => person.name = "somename" && person => person.addr = "some addr")
```

many thanks
Lĩnh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your condition as an `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` and use it in your query:

```
public Person GetPerson(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate)
{
    return (new myDbContext()).GetTable<Person>()
        .First(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had the following collection:

```
var people = (from pson in dbContext.GetTable<person>()).ToList();
```

You could write a method like this which will match a person based upon their name and address.

```
public Person GetPerson(string name, string address) 
{
    return people.Where(p => p.Name == name && p.Address == address).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then to invoke the function:

```
   public void YourFunction() {
       var person = GetPerson("Darren Davies", "My Address");

       if (person != null) {
             // Your code here
       }
   }
```